# Typecast to numbers only

Tags: php, variables, casting

Is there a way to typecast a variable to a number only?  Something like `$var=(int)$var;`, but not for integers?   `$var=is_numeric($var)?$var:NULL;` doesn't seem right.  Would `$var=1*$var;` be best? Thanks

Comment: @RocketHazmat.  23.43 is a valid number.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn.  I thought that float was only scientific notation.  I must have been wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `javascript` there are two different numeric types in PHP: `integer` and `float`. Therefore there are two ways how to convert to number:

```
$var = (integer) $var
$var = (float) $var
```

Both can be expressed as a function as well:

```
$var = intval($var);
$var = floatval($var);
```

Seems that you are looking for `(float)` or `floatval()` as you are using floating point numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Other than the above two solutions .. you can also try like

```
$var=$var+0; //adding a zero
```

but it won't make mush sense since every scripting language does the same (based on context). What I mean is .. the moment you try to do a mathematical operation it will be casted to number before performing the operation on it.

Hope it make some sense.